# Laravel no se instala correctamente en ubuntu

Tags: php, laravel, backend

He tenido varios errores al tratar de instalar Laravel de forma global e individual, lo  último que hice fue instalar php 7.2 e introducir

```
composer global require laravel/installer
```

después parece que todo se intalo correctamente pero al momento de introducir en la consola **laravel** me dice que no encuentra el comando ¿Cómo puedo intalar laravel? ya he intentado de todo[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

De acuerdo a la [documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8):

> Asegúrate de colocar el directorio `~/.composer/vendor/bin` en tu
>   `PATH` para que el ejecutable de laravel sea ubicado cuando ejecutes
>   el comando `laravel` en tu terminal.

Ejecuta el siguiente comando para editar el archivo:

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

Una vez que ya estés editando, agrega esta línea dentro del archivo:

```
export PATH="~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"
```

Guarda cambios y reinicia la terminal.

Para comprobar que está funcionando, después de reiniciarla, ejecuta:

`echo $PATH` y debería de devolverte el path.

Una vez que comprobaste ya puedes ejecutar el comando `laravel`.

Con esto, realmente no estás instalando Laravel, sino más bien configurando el instalador de Laravel. También puedes crear un nuevo proyecto de Laravel con el siguiente comando:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel nombreProyecto
```

Comment: Otra forma de instalar Laravel es mediante este comando  en el cual se coloca la ruta del scalfold teniendo todo listo para el proyecto: composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog   (donde blog sera el nombre de la carpeta de tu proyecto)

Comment: tu repuesta junto a esta linea de codigo fue la que me ayudo `alias laravel='~/.config/composer/vendor/bin/laravel' `