# mi ubuntu dice en consola que laravel no es un comando

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu

hoy realice la instalacion de composer junto con laravel, pero lo cual termino de instalar composer y requiero el global installer de laravel, ok instalo todos sus components normal, pero al tratar de crear una nueva app de laravel , me dice en la consola que el comando laravel no lo reconoce.

Comment: posible duplicado de https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/287213/laravel-no-se-instala-correctamente-en-ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

Es porque no has exportado la ruta al ejecutable como variable global. Prueba:

```
export PATH="~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"
```

Luego:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Para verificar:

```
echo $PATH
```

Luego reinicia tu consola y repite el último comando, el resultado debería ser el mismo: